# What is the reason of the change (PrimeFaces 8 to 10) that causes: "PanelGrid ... without a 'columns' attribute expects at least one <p:row> element"?

Tags: primefaces

I am essentially trying to narrow down exactly where in my code this error is caused at. The code ran on PrimeFaces 8.0 without any issues, but starting with PrimeFaces 10.0.0, I receive the following error:

> " PanelGrid "..." without a 'columns' attribute expects at least one <p:row> element.

I can see the specific spot at which the the exception is thrown in [PrimeFaces on GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/10.0.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/panelgrid/PanelGridRenderer.java#L207-L210). If anyone knows what exactly this change was implemented for or more broadly, what it does, I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check what has changed when and by whom in GitHub by clicking the "[blame](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blame/10.0.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/panelgrid/PanelGridRenderer.java#L207-L210)" button (top right of a source file).

Commits usually contain / start with the issue number the commit fixes. In this case [#6563: DataTable: filtering doesn't work inside p:panelGrid](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6563). You can find all the details and pull request there.

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for. I also did not know that about GitHub. That is going to be super useful in the future.